# C++ Why memory is allocated twice when const char*/char[] converted to std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, heap-memory, stdstring

I've learned from previous posts that `const char*` and `char[]` are stack-allocated. `std::string`, on the other hand, allocates memory on the heap.

Lets overload `new` and print allocated memory size:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t count) {
    std::cout << "allocated " << count << " bytes" << std::endl;
    return malloc(count);
}
```

And have a function with `const std::string&` parameter:

```
void passref(const std::string& any) {}
```

When I pass `const char*` or `char[]` I see two allocations, why?

```
    //1
    const char* a = "hello, this is some really long text.. and even longer";
    //2
    passref(a);
    //3
    char b[] = "hello, this is also a really long long long text";
    //4
    passref(b);
```

OUTPUT:

```
1                      
2
allocated 8 bytes
allocated 64 bytes         <--- ?
3
4
allocated 8 bytes
allocated 64 bytes         <--- ?
```

Comment: First to allocate the string and second to allocate the string contents.  If you passed a string reference then it won't allocate anything.

Comment: Not with this compiler https://godbolt.org/z/h4Tj38, only two allocations here. (and that is with optimizations turned off).

Comment: Which compiler and flags? I can't reproduce this on the GCC, Clang, and MSVC setups I tried.

Comment: @cup, Ignoring the fact that the three major `std::string` implementations size it at much more than 8 bytes, the language rarely dynamically allocates anything you don't explicitly ask for. Certainly not a temporary object like this.

Comment: @chris, This one is Visual Studio 2017 - Visual C++ 14.1

Comment: Never mind, I managed to reproduce this on MSVC locally. I forgot godbolt can't run MSVC binaries. It's very telling that this occurs only in debug builds, not release.

Comment: Visual studio debug builds do lots of extra work to detect undefined behaviour

Comment: `std::string` (and just about any other container object) starts with a default allocation size, and then if more is required, the memory is reallocated. Some compilers use a doubling scheme starting with 15-bytes allocated or so, other compilers could start with 8-bytes and then square the amount -- the standard doesn't require any specific growth strategy. Essentially the compiler tries to balance growth while minimizing the number of relatively costly allocations.

Comment: `const char* a = "hello, this is some really long text.. and even longer";` assigns the pointer to a string literal to `a`, string literals are in general neither on stack nor on the heap but in the data section. Where `std::string` has to store the data is not defined by the standard, most implementation use small string optimizations, so strings up to a certain length are enclosed in the `std::string` itself not requiring any additional memory allocation.